# Pass Function to Method Prototype

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Say I have a template:

```
template <typename T>
class foo{
    void (T::bar*)(int);
public:
    void setMethod(void (T::*)(int) f)
};
```

Is there a way to use a non-member function with this template?

I've tried:

- `foo<void>().setMethod(&func);`
- `foo<nullptr_t>().setMethod(&func);`

Comment: No, there's not. What is it you want to achieve, so I can suggest workarounds?

Comment: If you want to use sometimes member functions, and sometimes ordinary functions, you have to look for `<functional>` `function` and `bind`

Comment: @Wintermute I'd like to be able to create a `multi_map` with the key being the object type and the values being functions that I have added to the map for that type. My hope was to use `foo` as a value type for the `multi_map`. But that's way too big for the scope of one question.

Comment: @Christophe That's what I had been looking at but I was trying to avoid binding :(

Comment: You'd have more than one problem, in that case. `foo` is not a class but a class template; you cannot use it as key *or* value type for a map because it is not a type. Moreover, types are not objects, so you cannot use object types as keys. You could use `std::type_index`, but unless you can bind the objects to the member functions directly, what would you want to look up and how would you use it? You'd not know if the function you pull out of the map is compatible with the object you want to call it on.

Comment: How do you plan to call it?

Comment: @Wintermute Right so in my implementation `foo` is a child of the base class that I'm using in my values. As far as the keys I thought that I could use `decl_type` on the parameters. All this is way beyond the scope of this question though. Could you just post a "no" answer and then I'll accept that and I'll ask a new question and link you?

Comment: Well, alright. But it feels wrong to expect points just for "no," so I'll spend a few minutes mentioning things to look at for workarounds (so the answer is actually useful for posterity). Afterwards, I suggest we meet in chat, because I think your question is going to end up being a design question and opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The precise nature of a useful workaround depends on the nature of the problem, but it'll most likely involve `std::function` and `std::bind` (or lambdas). In very general terms, the trick is usually to rewrite `foo` in such a manner that it does not have to care about the kind of function that is bound to it (which is what `std::function` is for).

One way this might be done is

```
template <typename T>
class foo{
public:
  // Here we do not care about the type of function we're binding
  template<typename Func>
  void  setMethod(Func f) { func_ = f; }

  void callMethod(T &obj) { func_(obj); }

private:
  // only about its signature
  std::function<void(T&)> func_;
};
```

Given a type

```
struct A {
  void foo();
  void bar(int);
};
```

and a function

```
void qux(A &);
```

It is later possible to do any of

```
Foo<A> f;

f.setMethod(&A::foo);
f.setMethod(qux);
f.setMethod(std::bind(&A::bar, std::placeholders::_1, 2));
f.setMethod([](A &obj) { obj.foo(); });
```

Or indeed to call `setMethod` with anything that has an `operator()` accepting an `A&`.

In the event that Liskov substitution is required (which is the case for OP), this will not work because `foo` cannot offer an interface depending on the template arguments in a common base class. Then two options remain:

- If the object the function is to be called on can be bound at the same time as the function, it is possible to make `foo` a class, have it store a `std::function<void()>` and shove a `std::bind(&SomeClass::memberfunction, SomeObject)` into it.
- Otherwise, the best you're going to get without very evil hackery is limiting yourself to a common base class of what would have been `T` arguments to `foo`.

If your needs go beyond that, you're attempting to stretch the limits of the C++ type system and should probably reconsider your design.

Comment: For anyone else following up here, depending upon your application @Wintermute showed me how using a `std::tuple` could solve my problem, though I imagine it's not a universal solution.